# concatenate specific rows in one record and retrieve all data from first table

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

I need to concatenate two fields into a single row from two tables and retrieve all data from the first table and the concat specifications
I have two tables, something like this: 
Table1

```
ID              UserName     Location       Area
----------      ---------   -----------    -------------
1               user1       MX             area1
2               user2       US             area2
3               user3       US             area3
4               user4       MX             area4
5               user5       US             area5
```

and Table2:

```
    ID          UserNameBkp
----------      -----------
1               userA
2                    
3               userC
4               userD
5
```

and I want a query that shows the results like this:

```
ID              UserName           location       Area
----------      -------------      -----------    -------------
1               user1, userA       MX             area1
2               user2              US             area2
3               user3, userC       US             area3
4               user4, userD       MX             area4
5               user5              US             area5
```

I'm trying with `SELECT concat` but I can't manage to retrieve all data like this.

Comment: Show us the query you have tried to use. It will help us understand your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by using CONCAT only using case for NULL handling as like below but above one concat_ws is more suitable than this, leaving this answer just for one alternative:

```
SELECT t1.*,
   CONCAT(UserName, 
        CASE WHEN UserNameBkp IS NULL THEN 
            '' 
        ELSE 
            CONCAT(', ',UserNameBkp) 
        END) AS UserName
FROM tblone t1 
LEFT JOIN tbltwo t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be a simple `left join`:

```
select t1.*,
       concat_ws(', ', UserName, UserNameBkp) as UserName
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
You can use the below logic,

```
SELECT T1.ID,
T1.UserName,
      CASE
        WHEN T2.UserNameBkp IS NOT NULL THENT1.UserName||,||T2.UserNameBkp
        WHEN T1.UserName IS NULL THEN T2.UserNameBkp
        ELSE T1.UserName
       END AS UserName,
T1.Location,T1.Area FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
ON (T1.ID = T2.ID)
```